# What would a minimal serde deserialization implementation look like?

Tags: rust, serde

For a minimal implementation I'd like to see a program where a value of type `String` is deserialized into a value of type `MyStruct`:

```rust
struct MyVisitor;
impl<'de> serde::de::Visitor<'de> for MyVisitor {
    type Value = MyStruct;

    fn expecting(&self, formatter: &mut std::fmt::Formatter) -> std::fmt::Result {
        formatter.write_str("some string")
    }

    fn visit_str<E>(self, _v: &str) -> Result<Self::Value, E>
    where
        E: serde::de::Error,
    {
        /*

         Actual deserialization logic will eventually be here.

         For now it suffices that all given Strings are deserialized into
         { something: 42 }

        */
        return Ok(MyStruct { something: 42 });
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, serde::Deserialize)]
struct MyStruct {
    something: u32,
}

fn main() {
    let my_string: String = "foo".to_string();

    let my_visitor = MyVisitor;

    /*

     TODO:

        Deserialize my_string (of type String) into my_value (of type MyStruct)

     Maybe something like:

        let my_value: MyStruct = MyStruct::deserialize(my_string).unwrap();

     or maybe:

        let my_value: MyStruct = my_string.into()::deserialize<MyStruct>().unwrap();

     or what??

     */
    let my_value: MyStruct = which method of what to call here??

    println!("{:?}", my_value);
}
```

Which method of what would I need to call at the bottom of main, i.e. on the line that starts `let my_value: MyStruct =`?

Comment: The whole point of `serde` is that it decouples `struct` (de)serialization logic from the actual serialization format. "Which method of what to call here?" depends on the serialization format, not the target `struct`. E.g. you would call `serde_json::from_str (&my_string)` for JSON.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want your struct to be deserialized from a string representation. If so, you can implement `Deserialize` manually and rely on `String`'s own deserialization before doing your own validation. Like this:

```
use serde::de::{Deserialize, Deserializer};

#[derive(Debug)]
struct MyStruct {
    something: u32,
}

impl<'de> Deserialize<'de> for MyStruct {
    fn deserialize<D: Deserializer<'de>>(d: D) -> Result<Self, D::Error> {
        let s = String::deserialize(d)?;
        
        // do your deserialization logic here from `s`
        
        Ok(MyStruct { something: 42 })
    }
}
```

See it working on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=77fadd327c1ec724306677fc6506adbe) using a serde's `StrDeserializer` as a demonstration.